# How to fix 'must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause' with 'as' clause

Tags: sql, group-by, presto, amazon-athena

I am trying to get the number of request by hour of my CloudFront distribution using athena query.

I created cloudfront_logs table guided by [this Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html) in my sample_db

Below is the query I made to get the number of request by hour

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour',from_iso8601_timestamp(concat(concat(date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), 'T'), time))) as TIME, count(*) as CNT
FROM "sample_db"."cloudfront_logs" 
WHERE 
    from_iso8601_timestamp(concat(concat(date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), 'T'), time)) >= from_iso8601_timestamp('2019-05-29T00:00:00')
AND 
    from_iso8601_timestamp(concat(concat(date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), 'T'), time)) < from_iso8601_timestamp('2019-05-30T00:00:00')
GROUP BY TIME
ORDER BY TIME ASC;
```

However it returns error like this

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:8: '"date_trunc"('hour', "from_iso8601_timestamp"("concat"("concat"("date_format"("date", '%Y-%m-%d'), 'T'), "time")))' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause
```

Therefore, I replaced the `TIME` after `GROUP BY` to `date_trunc('hour',from_iso8601_timestamp(concat(concat(date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), 'T'), time)))`, and tried again.

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour',from_iso8601_timestamp(concat(concat(date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), 'T'), time))) as TIME, count(*) as CNT
FROM "sample_db"."cloudfront_logs" 
WHERE 
    from_iso8601_timestamp(concat(concat(date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), 'T'), time)) >= from_iso8601_timestamp('2019-05-29T00:00:00')
AND 
    from_iso8601_timestamp(concat(concat(date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), 'T'), time)) < from_iso8601_timestamp('2019-05-30T00:00:00')
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour',from_iso8601_timestamp(concat(concat(date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), 'T'), time)))
ORDER BY TIME ASC;
```

Finally, I got result.

I think, it should work with the first query also. Can I get any advice on the first query? Because It looks more simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just appears that Athena SQL does not make an alias used in the `SELECT` clause available in the `GROUP BY` clause at the same level.  Many versions of SQL do allow this, though.  You may try using a CTE here to make things less verbose:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT from_iso8601_timestamp(concat(concat(date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), 'T'), time)) AS ts
    FROM "sample_db"."cloudfront_logs"
)

SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('hour', ts) AS TIME,
    COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM cte
WHERE
    ts >= from_iso8601_timestamp('2019-05-29T00:00:00') AND
    ts <  from_iso8601_timestamp('2019-05-30T00:00:00')
GROUP BY
    DATE_TRUNC('hour', ts)
ORDER BY
    DATE_TRUNC('hour', ts);
```

Answer (score 6):

Athena is based on Presto. In Presto, you cannot use `SELECT` clause column aliases in the `GROUP BY` clause.
However, you can use identical expression, e.g.:

```
SELECT some_expression(a) FROM ... GROUP BY some_expression(a)
```

Also, you can refer to `SELECT` clause columns using their position in the SELECT list:

```
SELECT some_expression(a) FROM ... GROUP BY 1
```

This is ANSI SQL standard syntax. See [Presto GROUP BY documentation](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#group-by-clause) for mode details.

This can be used in `ORDER BY` as well, so your query would be something like

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour',from_iso8601_timestamp(concat(concat(date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), 'T'), time))) as TIME, count(*) as CNT
FROM "sample_db"."cloudfront_logs" 
WHERE ...
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```